# React Native release build failing on bundleJsAndAssets - hermes - index.android.bundle syntax error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, react-native-hermes

Trying to create an android release build with hermes enabled.
Been getting a weird error on bundleJsAndAssets that's coming from index.android.bundle:

```
  release/index.android.bundle:13990:31: error: ')' expected at end of function parameter list function validateBaseUrl(url: string) {
```

[image: react native android build error]

This function name does not exist in my codebase and I have no clue what could be causing it. Also haven't been able to find anything online. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's happened because flow type annotations are not stripped by babel. I guess that function `validateBaseUrl` located in `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob/URL.js`. In old react-native versions this file has no `@flow` declaration. It was fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/32566

So, you can try to upgrade react-native or change babel configuration. If you are using metro-react-native-babel-preset you can try to updated only it.